# Rearranging a series' terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

So i am asked to rearranje the terms in this series:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = 1- \frac 12 +\frac13-\frac14+...   $$

so that the sum of the series is equal to 0.
I've seen the Riemann series theorem but i can't still can't find a rearrangement that satisfies the condition.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Examples) has exactly this series as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article quoted in the comment, we get that the sum converges to $ln(2\sqrt{r})$ whenever $r$ is the ratio of positive to negative terms in the limit. Now, we want $ln(2\sqrt{r}) = 0$ so $2\sqrt{r} = 1$ so $r = \frac14$. This implies taking $1$ positive term for every $4$ negative terms will give you a sum that converges to $0$:

$1 - \frac 12 -\frac14 -\frac16 -\frac18 +\frac13 -\frac1{10} -\frac1{12} -\frac1{14} -\frac1{16} ...   $

Comment: An interesting exercise now would be to check this answer. That is, find a simple proof that this series does in fact converge to $0$- without appealing to the Reimann series theorem. Maybe it's not possible, but it might be.

Comment: Yes, it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2277682/134791