# Find the sum of the series (rearranged harmonic series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

> Find the value of the series:
>   $$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{14}-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{5}\cdots$$

I know that the alternated harmonic series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$ converges to $\ln2$, but here the order of the terms is different.

Comment: The harmonic sum most certainly does not converge to $\ln 2$.

Comment: With changing signs, I meant. (Leibniz)

Comment: Could you show your work on the problem? I think maybe it is being downvoted for this reason.

Comment: @Arthur I know, by the Riemann series theorem. I can't figure out this one, though.

Comment: You could group the terms five by five, add them together and look at the resulting expression. You get
$$
\frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{8n-6} - \frac{1}{8n-4} - \frac{1}{8n-2} - \frac{1}{8n} = \frac{16 n^2-20 n+3}{8 n (2 n-1) (4 n-3) (4 n-1)}
$$
as the general term in the sequence.

Comment: @Arthur And how would you sum these monsters?

Comment: @Did I have no idea apart from WolframAlpha. The only thing I can tell is that the sum is certain to converge.

Comment: Hint: Express the sum of the $5n$ first terms as a linear combination of the harmonic numbers $$H_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac1i,$$ for some well chosen values of $k$, then use the asymptotics $$H_k=\log k+\gamma+o(1)$$ to conclude.

Comment: The solution is $0$. I recall reading about rearrangements of this type and the general solution is

$$\ln (2)+\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(\frac{n}{m}\right)$$

Where, $n=1$ and $m=4$ for your rearrangement and $n$ and $m$ correspond to the length of the positive/negative term lengths.

Unfortunately, I do not remember how it was proved.

Comment: I think a proof of this would be a good answer to the question.

Comment: @GBeau And I am vain enough to believe that my previous comment contains everything needed to write down such a proof.

Comment: @GBeau

The general solution is simpler:
$$log\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)$$
if we rearrange the cancelling harmonic series

$$0=log(1)=1-1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+...$$

instead of the alternating harmonic series
(http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602987/134791)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summing various rearrangements of $1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911293/summing-various-rearrangements-of-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-cdots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case of a result by Fon Brown, L. O. Cannon, Joe Elich, and David G. Wright, [On Rearrangements of the Alternating Harmonic Series](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/CMJ/Brown135-138.pdf), The College Mathematics Journal, Vol. 16, No. 2. (Mar., 1985), pp. 135-138.

Answer (score 1):

Let us elaborate on @Arthur idea by regrouping the terms five by five.

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{8k+2}-\frac{1}{8k+4}-\frac{1}{8k+6}-\frac{1}{8k+8}\right)$$

Rewriting $\frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{4}{4(2k+1)}=\frac{4}{8k+4}$ simplifies the sum to four terms

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{8k+2}+\frac{3}{8k+4}-\frac{1}{8k+6}-\frac{1}{8k+8}\right)$$

that have all even denominator, so

$$S=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{4k+1}-\frac{3}{4k+2}+\frac{1}{4k+3}+\frac{1}{4k+4}\right)$$

The relation

$$\int_0^1 x^ndx=\frac{1}{n+1}
$$

changes the fractions into integrals
$$S=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^1 \left(x^{4k}-3x^{4k+1}+x^{4k+2}+x^{4k+3}\right)dx$$

Now we may interchange the order of summation and integration and use the sum of the geometric progression

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty cx^{ak+b} = \frac{cx^b}{1-x^a}$$

to obtain

$$\begin{align}
-2S&=\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(x^{4k}-3x^{4k+1}+x^{4k+2}+x^{4k+3}\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^1  \frac {1-3x+x^2+x^3}{1-x^4} dx \\
&=\int_0^1  \frac {1-2x-x^2}{(1+x)(1+x^2)} dx \\
&=\int_0^1 \left( \frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx\\
&=\left(\log(2)-\log(2)\right)=0\\
\end{align}$$

as in [showing $ 1-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{3}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots=0 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275508/showing-1-frac32-frac13-frac14-frac15-frac36-frac1).

The procedure here is very similar to one of the four proofs Jack D'Aurizio gives to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911293/summing-various-rearrangements-of-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-cdots), which includes the one here.